# How to display more than one value as separate row in matrix column grouping in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am facing trouble displaying multiple result set in rows in matrix column grouping.

My Data set -

[image]

My desire result set -

[image]

My design -

I did row grouping combination of **Code** and **Tax**, column grouping on  **Exam**.

[image]

Based on my design, I get this result -

[image]

Is there a way that I can get desired result?

I would appreciate if someone helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love to solve this in the comment itself but i do not have enough reputation to comment. So based on the provided data in the question below is my answer.

In your data set add another column for the grouping the data.
Add `DENSE_RANK() over (partition by exam order by item) AS Grouping` and then change your row grouping to the new column added `[Grouping]`

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The Exam column filled with A3 Items and doesn't leave the empty cells like shown in the example. I accepted the answer because somewhere it is correct.